# ¿Cómo obtener el primer día y el último día del mes actual con C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

hola comunidad estoy haciendo un formulario en el cual tengo dos `input` de tipo `date` en los cuales en uno tengo la `fecha de inicio` que es la `fecha actual` y uso  algo así `Fecha_Inicio = DateTime.Now`, y en el otro tengo la `fecha final` en la cual quiero poner el día ultimo del mes en base a la fecha inicio pero no se como realizar esto ya que los valores obtenidos los quiero poner en el `bind-value` de los input.

estos son los input que tengo en el formulario:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" @bind-value="@Pre.Fecha_Inicio" />
  <input type="date" class="form-control" @bind-value="@Precio.Fecha_Final" />
```

para asignarle la fecha actual al input llamado `fecha_inicio` lo que hice es esto el valor se lo puse en el `bind-value`:

```
public Precio Pre = new Precio()
    {
        Fecha_Inicio = DateTime.Now,
        
    };
```

pero a partir de este punto no se como asignarle la fecha_final en base a la fecha_inicio estoy intentando algo como esto pero no me funciona:

```
public Precio Pre = new Precio()
    {
        Fecha_Inicio = DateTime.Now,
        Fecha_Final = DateTime.Now.LastDayOfMonth()
    };

    public static DateTime LastDayOfMonth(this DateTime inDate)
    {
        var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(inDate.Year, inDate.Month);
        return new DateTime(inDate.Year, inDate.Month, daysInMonth);
    }
```

Comment: cual es el valor de fecha_final en su codigo ahora?

Comment: no tiene ningún valor ya que aun no puedo lograr pasarle uno, no acepta el método LastDayOfMonth

Comment: Cambia la declaracion de la funcion a: `public static DateTime LastDayOfMonth( DateTime inDate)`

Y Fecha_Final a `Fecha_Final = LastDayOfMonth(Fecha_Inicio)`

Comment: Fecha_Final = LastDayOfMonth(Fecha_Inicio) no le puedo pasar fecha_inicio dice que la variable no existe en el  contexto actual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes que nada parece dos temas

**TEMA 1: Obtener el ultimo día del mes.**
Si quieres tener el ultimo día del mes, y ya tienes la fecha, yo utilizo este metodo rápido que es **tomar el primer dia de ese mes, sumar un mes y restar un día**
Por ejemplo

```
new DateTime(unaFecha.Year, unaFecha.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

También se puede hacer como indicas con la ayuda del método [DateTime.DaysInMonth](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.daysinmonth?view=netcore-3.1)

Podes ver el ejemplo funcionando aquí

- https://dotnetfiddle.net/wyaVXJ

En tu ejemplo seria

```
 Fecha_Inicio = DateTime.Now,
 Fecha_Final = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

Pero bueno, es otra alternativa simplemente a obtener el valor del ultimo dia del mes

TEMA 2: Blazor, cambio de fecha y
(esto es similiar a una pregunta que realizaste anteriormente
Pero paso el ejemplo

- https://blazorfiddle.com/s/na9p5kew
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tienes en blazor algo asi

```
<div class="wrapper">
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date </label>
        <input id="txtDate" type="date" required @bind-value="_date1" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date (last date of Month)</label>
        <input id="txtDate" type="date" required @bind-value="_date2" />
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

En tu codigo puedas cambiar la segunda fecha al momento de que se bindea la primera (hay que ver si te sirve este tipo de comportamiento)

```
private DateTime _date1Value;
 private DateTime _date1 { 
     get {
         return _date1Value;
     } 
     set{
         _date1Value = value;
         _date2 = new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
     } 
} 

 private DateTime _date2 { get; set; }
```

Ademas otra aternativa mas simple puede ser que la propiedad de tu clase **Precio** la puedas implementar completamente para que no este "implicita", asi cuando se setea el valor de *Fecha_Inicio* cambias el valor de *Fecha_Final*
Un ejemplo sencillo

```
  public class Precio {

private DateTime _fechaInicio;
public DateTime Fecha_Inicio { 
    get {
        return _fechaInicio;
    } 
    set {
        _fechaInicio = value;
        Fecha_Final = new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    } 
}

public DateTime Fecha_Final { get; set; }
```

}

Y aquí el ejemplo en Blazor con una clase Precio "sencilla" pero para ver como seria la implementación completa de la propiedad para agregar funcionalidad en el set del valor

- https://blazorfiddle.com/s/woruo43k

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía

Comment: muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda , era justo lo que quería hacer que al elegir una fecha en otro input date se colocara la fecha de fin de mes correspondiente , me  funciono perfecto

Answer (score 0):

DateTime fecha_seleccionada = DateTime.Parse("2023-01-31"); // para la fecha actual es DateTime.Now

DateTime primer_dia_mes_anterior = new DateTime(fecha_seleccionada.Year, fecha_seleccionada.Month, 1).AddMonths(-1);

DateTime ultimo_dia_mes_anterior = new DateTime(primer_dia_mes_anterior.Year, primer_dia_mes_anterior.Month, primer_dia_mes_anterior.Day).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

Console.WriteLine(primer_dia_mes_anterior.ToString() + " / " + ultimo_dia_mes_anterior.ToString());

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que modifiques la estructura de tu respuesta para que sea más clara. Explica tu código y añade el código dentro de las secciones de código para que sea más fácil de entender.

Answer (score 0):

**//MES ANTERIOR**

DateTime fecha_seleccionada = DateTime.Parse("2023-01-31"); // para la fecha actual es DateTime.Now

DateTime primer_dia_mes_anterior = new DateTime(fecha_seleccionada.Year, fecha_seleccionada.Month, 1).AddMonths(-1);

DateTime ultimo_dia_mes_anterior = new DateTime(primer_dia_mes_anterior.Year, primer_dia_mes_anterior.Month, primer_dia_mes_anterior.Day).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

**//MES ACTUAL**

DateTime fecha_actual = DateTime.Now;

DateTime primer_dia_mes_actual = new DateTime(fecha_actual.Year, fecha_actual.Month, 1);

DateTime ultimo_dia_mes_actual = new DateTime(primer_dia_mes_actual.Year, primer_dia_mes_actual.Month, primer_dia_mes_actual.Day).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

Console.WriteLine(primer_dia_mes_anterior.ToString() + " / " + ultimo_dia_mes_anterior.ToString());

Console.WriteLine(primer_dia_mes_actual.ToString() + " / " + ultimo_dia_mes_actual.ToString());

Comment: Hola Cristobal, gracias por colaborar con tu respuesta, pero has dado dos respuestas, en vez de una, y con cosas repetidas, además no hay ninguna explicación. Mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada. Te sugiero que edites tu respuesta para que se adapte a los lineamientos del sitio.